# WinAPI to check is the 8.3 alias supported

Tags: winapi, filesystems, disk

According to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#short_vs._long_names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names) the 8.3 aliases are optional.

What is the API to check if there is support for 8.3 alias for particular file or device?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Remy - it is just a link, feel free to use it.

Comment: @HansPassant: was just trying to get you credit for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DeviceIoControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216.aspx) or [`ZwFsControlFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566462.aspx) to send a [`FSCTL_QUERY_PERSISTENT_VOLUME_STATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545496.aspx) control code to the volume.  It fills a [`FILE_FS_PERSISTENT_VOLUME_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540280.aspx) struct, whose `VolumeFlags` field will have the `PERSISTENT_VOLUME_STATE_SHORT_NAME_CREATION_DISABLED` flag enabled if 8.3 aliasing is disabled.

See the following article for more details and a code example:

[Query Volume Setting for 8.3 State](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304374/Query-Volume-Setting-for-State-Windows)